# Can't validate blank input in flow

Tags: visual-workflow, inputfield

When I am doing input validation using formula `ISNULL({!date1})` This formula is working as expected but if I use `NOT(ISNULL({!date1}))` or and chain formula validation is not working.

[image: flow image]

Edit:
I have 2 fields and both of them are non-mandatory but one of them should be filled. So I was using `OR(NOT(ISNULL({!Date})), NOT(ISNULL({!date1})) )` . but if both fields are blank and not required flow don't validate these fields.
Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the user leaves the field blank and the field is not required, the flow doesn’t validate.
As for formula `NOT(ISNULL({!date1}))` I was leaving the field blank, it was not getting validated.
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_ref_elements_screen_validate.htm&type=5